# UITableView not loading Firebase Snapshot Data.

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

I have a Firebase database with structure: 
"users"
-uid
   - name 
   - email 
. I would like to input the "users" email and name into a UITableviewController tableview in XCode. The data can be seen in my console, but is not appended to my Table View

```
class DictionaryTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
let cellID = "Cell"
var refHandle: UInt!
var userList = [Users]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  //Set firebase database reference
  ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

  //Retrieve posts and listen for changes
  refHandle = ref?.child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
     //Code that executes when child is added
     if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
        let user = Users()
        user.name = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as? String
        print(user.name)
        user.email = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "email").value as? String
        print(user.email)
        print("databaseHandle was called")
        for user in self.userList {
           print(user)
           self.userList.append(user)

        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
     }
  })
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return userList.count
  }
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellID)
     cell.textLabel?.text = userList[indexPath.row].name.self
     cell.textLabel?.text = userList[indexPath.row].email.self
     return cell

   }
 }
}
```

Comment: reload table on main thread.

Comment: Why are get the self of the name and email ? `userList[indexPath.row].name.self`

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

And after the if let statements add this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I've added this to my code, but it still does not show anything on the tableview. See code below.

Answer (score 0):

Like so; does not show the data on the table still.

`//Retrieve posts and listen for changes
   func fetchUserData(with completion:@escaping (Bool)->()) {
      refHandle = ref?.child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { 
       (snapshot) in
         //Code that executes when child is added
         if (snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]) != nil {
            let user = Users()
            user.name = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as? 
            String
            print(user.name)
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
               user.email = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "email").value 
               as? String
               print(user.email)
               print("databaseHandle was called")
               for user in self.userList {
                  print(user)
                  self.userList.append(user)
                  self.userTable.reloadData()
               }`